# A python function returning signature of it's own run time arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, signature, introspection, inspect

I'd like a function:

```py
def sig(*args, **kwargs):
    """User-friendly inspect.Signature construction"""
    # I'm guessing some introspection of frames or something...
    pass
```

that does what its doc says: Make `Signature` instances easily.

An example of it's behavior would be:

```py
>>> sig(a, b: int, c=1, d: str='bar')
<Signature (a, b: int, c=1, d: str = 'bar')>
>>> sig(something_else)
<Signature (something_else)>
>>> sig()
<Signature ()>
```

It seems some wizardry using the `inspect` module's ability to rear frames would do, but not so far I've only managed to come up with ugly hacks.

Anyone have something graceful?

## Edit (~hour later)

Responders pointed out that my desires for simplicity were syntactically impossible. So I'll reword the question: What solutions might approach that simplicity, possibly sacrificing some completeness (e.g. without annotations).

Comment: Function call syntax and function definition syntax might look vaguely similar, but their meanings are far too different and incompatible for this to work.

Comment: "What solutions might approach that simplicity, possibly sacrificing some completeness (e.g. without annotations)." - pass a lambda to `signature`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, you're on to something. We can't get annotations in lambdas, but I didn't realize we could get defaults in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering everything the responders and commenters have said, here what I got.

The exact wish is syntactically impossible, but are two ways to achieve the simplicity sought for.

Just use `inspect.signature` as a decorator:

```py
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> @signature
... def sig1(a, b: int, c=0, d: float=0.0): ...
>>> @signature
... def sig2(something_else): ...
>>> @signature
... def sig3(): ...
>>>
>>> sig1
<Signature (a, b: int, c=0, d: float = 0.0)>
>>> sig2
<Signature (something_else)>
>>> sig3
<Signature ()>
```

But if you need to have something more dynamic, I propose the following:

```py
def sig(obj: Union[Signature, Callable, Mapping, None] = None, return_annotations=_empty, **annotations):
    """Convenience function to make a signature or inject annotations to an existing one.
    """
    if obj is None:
        return Signature()
    if callable(obj):
        obj = Signature.from_callable(obj)  # get a signature object from a callable
    if isinstance(obj, Signature):
        obj = obj.parameters  # get the parameters attribute from a signature
    params = dict(obj)  # get a writable copy of parameters
    if not annotations:
        return Signature(params.values(), return_annotation=return_annotations)
    else:
        assert set(annotations) <= set(params), \
            f"These argument names weren't found in the signature: {set(annotations) - set(params)}"
        for name, annotation in annotations.items():
            p = params[name]
            params[name] = Parameter(name=name, kind=p.kind, default=p.default, annotation=annotation)
        return Signature(params.values(), return_annotation=return_annotations)
```

Demo:

```py
>>> s = sig(lambda a, b, c=1, d='bar': ..., b=int, d=str)
>>> s
<Signature (a, b: int, c=1, d: str = 'bar')>
>>> # showing that sig can take a signature input, and overwrite an existing annotation:
>>> sig(s, a=list, b=float)  # note the b=float
<Signature (a: list, b: float, c=1, d: str = 'bar')>
>>> sig()
<Signature ()>
>>> sig(lambda a, b=2, c=3: ..., d=int)  # trying to annotate an argument that doesn't exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AssertionError: These argument names weren't found in the signature: {'d'}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @D34DStone pointed out, what you want to achieve isn't possible, because it isn't valid syntax.
However, you can instead pass your "spec" as a string.

Here is one way to achieve it.  Not very pretty though... (and possibly not secure).

```
def sig(x):
    locals = dict(x=x)
    exec('''
import inspect
def f(%s): pass
s = inspect.signature(f)
    ''' % x, {}, locals)
    return locals['s']

sig("a, b: int, c=1, d: str='bar'")
=> <Signature (a, b:int, c=1, d:str='bar')>
```

Comment: Sorry @D34DStone, the last part of your answer made me believe you didn't understand the answer. Edit and I'll upvote.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Indeed, I won't be able to have the simplicity I desired. Your hack resembles what I did, but prefer not to have to parse strings and exec. I'll see what others have to propose, and if nothing better, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'll edit my post slightly to invite alternative solutions to the "simplify Signature instance construction" problem.

Answer (score -1):

In the newest python 3.8.2 you can't pass value to function with its type annotated.

```
File "main.py", line 10
    print(sig(1, 2: int, c=3, d:str = "Hello"))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also, no matter what types you specified, it is the same during runtime. But you can try to deduce types this way:

```
>>> type(123).__name__
'int'
```

Comment: I'm not trying to deduce types at runtime. I'm trying to create `inspect.Signature` instances in a more user-friendly way.